# Fitting a bagging model on a dataset without splitting the dataset into training and test

Tags: r, random-forest

I wish to fit a bagging model on a dataset with dependent variable "Class" as either "Good" or "Bad" and many independent variables including "Age", "Duration" and "Amount" without splitting the data into training and test.

I tried to make the bagging model but I could only make it with a training/test split.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can go about evaluating the model, but you can fit models with your full data set.

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(baguette)
library(dplyr)


penguins_df <- penguins %>%
  select(species, bill_length_mm, bill_depth_mm, flipper_length_mm, body_mass_g)

penguins_bagged <- bagger(x = penguins_df[,-1], y = penguins_df$species,
                          base_model = 'CART',
                          times = 5)

penguins_bagged
#> Bagged CART (classification with 5 members)
#> 
#> Variable importance scores include:
#> 
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   term              value std.error  used
#>   <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
#> 1 flipper_length_mm 130.       4.05     5
#> 2 bill_length_mm    128.       1.84     5
#> 3 bill_depth_mm     108.       3.38     5
#> 4 body_mass_g        97.1      3.53     5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>